# Documentation for recovery behaviors in move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for documentation or research material on recovery_behaviors in move_base, if such thing is available as I couldn't find any. I am assuming someone must have published something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304651/documentation-for-recovery-behaviors-in-move_base/) by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 685 on 2018-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the best I have for you as far as published material: http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/icra2010_marder-eppstein.pdf

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-10-03**:
Thanks, Well recovery behaviors are kind of stupid so I guess I shouldn't expect any publication on that.